# Delay & Queue php execution

Tags: php, asynchronous, queue, background-process

I am having a Php application behind a CDN & Varnish Cache. Each time content is edited a php function is invoked which will purge cache in both the CDN & Varnish Cache. I want the script to wait 30 seconds before it clears CDN. In case multiple edits happen all this must wait 30 seconds and then the action should happen. However, I want to do this in scalable way. I don't want to block resources or process in the waiting(Asynchronously i think).

There will be around 10 - 20 such executions per hour. I think the key is somehow running it in background.